# how to make timer start on key press Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the follow code:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text timerText;
    public Text votingResults;
    public float periodToVote;
    //public float periodToStartVoting;

    private bool objectDestroyed;
    private bool timerIsRunning;
    private bool timesUp = false;
    private float time;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        votingResults.enabled = false;
        timerText.text = "Press on Space for voting to start";
        timerIsRunning = false;
        objectDestroyed = false;
        timesUp = false;
        time = Time.time;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            Debug.Log("The function is running correctly");
            time = Time.time;
            timerIsRunning = true;
            votingResults.enabled = true;
        }

        if (!objectDestroyed && timerIsRunning)
        {
            float votinEndingTime = periodToVote - Time.time;

            string minutes = ((int)votinEndingTime / 60).ToString();
            string seconds = (votinEndingTime % 60).ToString("f0");

            timerText.text = "Voting Ends in: " + "\n" + seconds;

            if (votinEndingTime < 0)
            {
                objectDestroyed = true;
                Destroy(timerText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is being added to an object. The problem is that the timer starts whenever the scene starts and not when the space is being pressed. I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Please if there is something which is not clear or needs more explanation then let me know in the comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this in `Update` I would recommend a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and only start it in `Update` if conditions are met .. that makes it a bit saver and easier to controll.

```c#
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text timerText;
    public Text votingResults;
    public float periodToVote;
    private bool isRunning;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start ()
    {
        votingResults.enabled = false;
        timerText.text = "Press on Space for voting to start";
    }

    private IEnumerator RunTimer()
    {
         isRunning = true;
         var passedTime = 0.0f;
         while(passedTime < periodToVote)
         {
              string minutes = Mathf.RoundToInt((periodToVote - passedTime) / 60).ToString();
              string seconds = Mathf.RoundToInt(periodToVote - passedTime).ToString("f0");
              timerText.text = "Voting Ends in: " + "\n" + seconds;

              passedTime += Time.deltaTime;
              yield return null;
         }

         Destroy(timerText);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update ()
    {
        if (if(!isRunning) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Sarting Timer");
            votingResults.enabled = true;
            StartCoroutine(RunTimer());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I think there is something wrong as passedTime is always the same

Comment: oh sorry I totally forgod that `passedTime += Time.deltaTime;` before the `yield`

Comment: Thanks so much. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Because you calculate `votingEndingTime` using `Time.time` which is the current time in your game and subtracting it makes not sense. You have to use the time `Space` is pressed like this and add `periodToVote` to it for finding when the voting will end:

```
float votinEndingTime = periodToVote + time;
```

Because `time` is the value when `Space` is pressed.

Then you can check if time is up like this:

```
if(Time.time > votingEndingTime)
{
    objectDestroyed = true;
    Destroy(timerText);
}
```